# Partition after a group by in hive

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose there is a table with some data and a column with dates:

```
column1, column2, date
a, a, 2016
a, b, 2016
a, c, 2017
b, d, 2017
b, e, 2017
```

The case is to count column2 occurences for each column1 and apply the min date for each column1.

The first part is an easy group by. The second could be obtained with a partition by clause. But how can I combine these two in a smart and clean way?
Is partitioning really needed to get the min date? Any wise suggestions would be great!

Expected output:

```
column1, count, min_date
a, 3, 2016
b, 2, 2017
```

Comment: add expected ouput

Comment: @bry888 add your code too

Comment: I have no code, this is a question about writing code :) About formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `group by`:

```
select column1, 
       count(distinct column2) count, --remove distinct if you need count not null column2 by column1
                                      --use count(*) if you need count all rows by column1
       min(date)               min_date
from table
group by column1
```

Let's test it:

```
select column1, 
       count(distinct column2) count, --remove distinct if you need count not null column2 by column1
                                      --use count(*) if you need count all rows by column1
       min(date)               min_date
from (
select 
stack(6,
'a','a', 2016, 
'a','b', 2016, 
'a','c', 2017, 
'b','d', 2017, 
'b','e', 2017, 
'c','e', 2015) as( column1, column2, date)
) s
group by column1
```

Results:

```
a   3   2016    
b   2   2017    
c   1   2015
```

Note that min_date selected minimum for each column1 value.

Comment: This solution doesn't give the min date for each column1, but the min date in general, for the whole column

Comment: @bry888  Yes, it will give you min date for each `column1` value, not absolute minimum because there is the same `group by`

Comment: @bry888 You need analytics functions (using partition by) only if you need to aggregate by different groups in a single query

Comment: Thank you! It appeared there was some mess in my data... Your solution works fine :)